# When more and less links click, list items show/hide using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide, html-lists

I have a big item list that I wanted to hide, and then a button called #more will sow 5 more. So far I was able to show more, but when I show less with a button called #less, script stuck.

following is my code and [fiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/cUUfS/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="more">more</a>
<a href="#" id="less">less</a>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    ...
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var visible = 7;
    $('ul li:gt('+(visible - 1)+')').hide();

$('#more').click(function() {
    if ($('ul li:visible:last').is(':last-child')) {
        return false;
    }

    var currentIndex = $('ul').children('li:visible:last').index(),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + (visible + 1);
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul li:lt(' + nextIndex + '):gt(' + currentIndex + ')').show();
});

$('#less').click(function() {
    if ($('ul li:visible:first').is(':first-child')) {
        return false;
    }

    var currentIndex = $('ul').children('li:visible:first').index();
    var prevIndex = (currentIndex - (visible + 1));

    $('ul li').hide();
    if(prevIndex == 0)
        $('ul li:lt(' + currentIndex + ')').show();
    else
        $('ul li:lt(' + currentIndex + '):gt(' + prevIndex + ')').show();
});
});
```

Comment: Fiddle was using mootools, changed to jquery

Comment: Also, do you want to show/hide more/less items or move forwards and backwards through the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what I think you want and it is a lot cleaner, you were doing a lot more jQuery calls than were needed.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var visible = 7, $lis = $('ul li'), max = $lis.length;        
    function showUpToIndex(index) {
        $lis.hide();
        $lis.slice(0, index).show();
    }

    showUpToIndex(visible);

    $('#more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        visible = visible + 5;
        if (visible > max) visible = max;

        showUpToIndex(visible);
    });

    $('#less').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        visible = visible - 5;
        if (visible < 0) visible = 0;

        showUpToIndex(visible);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUUfS/12/

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is with your currentIndex in your less function. It is finding the index of the VISIBLE elements only, not the index of your FIRST li that is visible out of ALL your elements, if you see what im saying. @Richard D's answer looks good to me, but if you wanted to know where your problem was I believe it starts there